# How add specific type column by liqiubase

Tags: liquibase

Postgresql has type INTERVAL for column. But I didn`t found simple way to create table with such column.

I have solution with two steps:
1. Create table by liquibase changeSet.
2. Use changeSet with sqlFile. Sql file contain sql for add column.

Example changeSet:

```
  <changeSet author="author" id="add-testmy-table-v1">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <tableExists tableName="testmy"/>
        </not>
    </preConditions>

    <createTable tableName="testmy">
        <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="BIGSERIAL">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" primaryKeyName="PK_testmy"/>
        </column>
        <column name="created_at" type="TIMESTAMP(6) WITHOUT TIME ZONE"/>
        <column name="employee_id" type="BIGINT"/>            
    </createTable>

</changeSet>

<changeSet author="liquibase-docs" id="sql-example">
    <sqlFile dbms="postgresql" encoding="utf8" path="testmy.sql" relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
</changeSet>
```

testmy.sql file contain:

ALTER TABLE testmy
ADD COLUMN began_at INTERVAL ,
ADD COLUMN ended_at INTERVAL ;

Could anyone show another variant to solve such problem?

Comment: Why don't you just add `<column name="began_at " type="INTERVAL"/>` in your `createTable` changeset? Is there any error?

Comment: Thank hsthame, in case postgresql database - no errors.

Comment: So is it working as you need it to work?

Comment: In my case (application will work only with postgresql) - yes. Thanks a lot :)